# How can I correctly retrieve the value inserted into a submitted form inside the controller method that handle the request in Spring MVC?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am working on a Spring MVC application. Untill now to perform a form I always used jQuery (that retrieve the data inside my form and perform an AJAX call sending a JSON object to the controller).

Now I can't do in this way and I have to handle it differently.

So in my page I have this form:

```
<form id="reg-form" name="reg-form" action="iscrizioneStep2" method="post">
    <fieldset>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="cf">Codice fiscale:</label>
            <input type="text" id="cf" name="cf" class="form-control input-mm" placeholder="Inserisci il tuo codice fiscale" data-validation="[NOTEMPTY]" data-validation-label="codice fiscale" aria-required="true" tabindex="10">
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" tabindex="20"></div>
        </div>

        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-block submit-btn" aria-label="prosegui la registrazione" tabindex="30">Passaggio 2</button>

    </fieldset>
</form>
```

The **action** is **iscrizioneStep2** so I think that it should be the resource toward the form content is submitted.

This form contain an **input** tag having **id="cf"** where the user insert a String.

Now I have this controller method in my controller class

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/iscrizioneStep2",  method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String iscrizioneStep2(Model model) {
    return "iscrizioneStep2";
}
```

Now my problem is: how can I retrive the previous textual value inserted in this form inside my **iscrizioneStep2()** controller method? (I have not to use a model object but I want to retrieve this value inside the POST request from my controller method)

Comment: There is a nice little starter here :
http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-form-handling-example/

Comment: If you not using spring tags, but only html form you can always use HttpServletRequest object and get parameter from it. public String iscrizioneStep2(HttpServletRequest request){ String cf =  request.getParameter("cf")

Answer (score 0):

Solved by myself implementing this controller method:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/iscrizioneStep2", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String iscrizioneStep2(Model model, HttpServletRequest request) {

    System.out.println("INTO iscrizioneStep2()");
    String codicFiscale = request.getParameter("cf");
    System.out.println("CODICE FISCALE: " + codicFiscale);

    return "iscrizioneStep2";
}
```

Comment: Did you even try `@RequestParam`?